# What is a plant-and-animal safe way to kill a hive of yellowjackets?

Tags: grass, insects, domestic-animals, clover, wasps

I’ve seen plenty of questions on here about what wasps are doing to plants. Specifically **I want my hive *gone***.

I have a large backyard where I try to keep grass, cloves, and insects plentiful. (These are food for my chickens [check my bio for adorable pictures]). [Yellowjackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowjacket) of the Vespinae subfamily are dangerous to me and prey on the insects in my yard.

I need a way to eliminate the hive in the chicken coop that won’t harm me or the plants and insects in my yard. (Leaving the bodies in the coop is fine. My chickens love spicy food and have rendered multiple ant mounds extinct in the past.)

What do you guys recommend?

Comment: If you can organize it without getting stung to death, trickle water continuously onto the nest. They don't like wet feet and will soon leave. Otherwise, get a professional to smoke them out.